# Map latitude and longitude is showing in sea in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

From a json feed am getting all the latitude and longitude and adding all in mapview. Am gettin different markers.but all the points are showing in sea. this is my code. can anyone help me please

```
MapItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    url = "http://dentonsweb.com/app/html/android/get.php?what=Hotels&lat=51.507222&lon=-0.1275&pg=0";
    System.out.println("url is "+url);
    Jsonfunctions jParser = new Jsonfunctions();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = results.getJSONObject(i);

            id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            System.out.println("name is " + name);
            adress = c.getString(TAG_ADRRESS);
            latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
            latitudeAry.add(c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE).toString());
            longitude = c.getString(TAG_lONGITUDE);
            latitudeAry.add(c.getString(TAG_lONGITUDE).toString());
            distance = c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
            image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
            phone = c.getString(TAG_TELEPHONE);
            telphonenumberAry
                    .add(c.getString(TAG_TELEPHONE).toString());
            NameAry.add(c.getString(TAG_NAME).toString());
            resourceAry.add(new ResourceClass(point,id, name, adress,image,
                    distance, latitude, longitude, phone));
            System.out.println("arraooosdospodpsodps  " + resourceAry);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    mc = mapView.getController();
    listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.pin);
    itemizedoverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable,mapView);
    for (int i = 0; i < resourceAry.size(); i++) {
        // latitude = resourceAry.get(i).getLatitude();
         System.out.println("latitude is " + latitude);
         String latitude = resourceAry.get(i).getLatitude();
         String longitude = resourceAry.get(i).getLongitude();
        // longitude = resourceAry.get(i).getLongitude();
         String name = resourceAry.get(i).getName();
         System.out.println("Name is" + name);
         String adress = resourceAry.get(i).getAdress();

        if (!latitude.equals("") && !longitude.equals("")) {
            Double latitude_next = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
            Double longitude_next = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

            point = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude_next * 1E6),
                    (int) (longitude_next * 1E6));
            System.out.println("point is " + point);

            overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,resourceAry.get(i).getName(),resourceAry.get(i).getAdress());
            // System.out.println( " spanned text: " +
            // Html.fromHtml(Texte));

            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            listOfOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        }
    }
    mc.animateTo(point);
    mc.setZoom(13);
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

@harish -- 
You get latitude & longitudes like 51.509998321533,-0.12999999523163 
but in android geopoint accepts only int values.
now create a function which will take these values & restric them upto 6 decimal points & you will get result as you wanted
Function will be like

```
 double roundTwoDecimals(double d){
      DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
      return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
  }
```

this way you will get double  value & then multiply it with 10E6 & you will get int which you need to use in creating GeoPoints..

Comment: @harish -- GeoPoint constructor accept only int right? Now do you know integer limit?? If you take more than 6 decimal points it will cross int limit & so geopoint on your map displays at wrong location. Have you tried what I suggested?? & isi t working??

Answer (score 0):

I am not suere if it makes a difference but the line

```
latitudeAry.add(c.getString(TAG_lONGITUDE).toString());
```

has a lowercase L in lONGITUDE